# Java properties Files and Gradle

Tags: java, properties, gradle, testng

I have a Java TestNG project set up with gradle running test suites. Currently, most of the tests are pulling certain parameters out of a constants.properties file. How would I modify these on the command line when running the gradle task? Will `gradle -DapplicationKey=0000` replace the line `applicationKey=1234` in my constants.properties file?

Edit:
To be a bit more clear about the situation and the question, my constants.properties file contains around 400 to 500 properties that are already defined. I would like to avoid rewriting those properties in gradle completely. I just want to override those properties from the command line when Jenkins runs the same commands as part of that build job.

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass system properties to the JVM used to run tests. Here is a way to configure all tasks of type `Test`:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
  systemProperty 'applicationKey', System.getProperty('applicationKey', '1234')
}
```

or just one task

```
test {
    useTestNG()
    systemProperties = [
            applicationKey: System.getProperty('applicationKey', '1234')
    ]
}
```

You can also copy all system properties from the Gradle environment to the child virtual machine with `systemProperties = System.getProperties()`

Comment: This is great, but I'd like to do this on the command line. Reason for this is the targets that we normally hit are registered in the constants.properties file, but the targets that we want jenkins to hit are not. I'd like to set jenkins to override the constants.properties file in the command line to hit the jenkins targets.

Comment: Have you tried my code? If your tests read system properties and you start them in Jenkins with `gradle  test -DapplicationKey=0000` what happens?